# how to maintain users history on website in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have a website and i want to show to user "your recent visits" and this will happen when a user is coming more than one time if user visit website first time nothing will appear but if it comes again whatever he has search before it will show in a box. For this i have work on cookies but this is not working fine my code is below:

```
    <?php
       $pageName = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
       $site_name = 'www.xyz.com';
       setcookie('site_name',$site_name,time()+(60*60));
     ?>

      <body style="margin:0 auto; width:400px">
      <br /><h2>Cookie Example</h2>

     <?php
        // print_r($_COOKIE);
        echo "<strong>Cookie has been Created:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$site_name;
        echo "<br>";
        if(isset($_COOKIE['site_name']))
        {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<strong>wellcome back</strong>";
        echo "<br>";echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<strong>Wellcome</strong>";
    }

    ?>

       <a href="visit1.php">Visit 1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <a href="visit2.php">Visit 2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <a href="visit3.php">Visit 3</a>
```

is there any other way to get the data of visitor.

Comment: without saving to database?

Comment: yes without saving in database

Answer (score 0):

1. Pages (which appear in the history) should be represented as short as possible. Assign a unique ID to every page.
2. You should work out a method, which stores a series of page IDs in a simple string. You should write routines which converts an array of pages to that string, and also one which creates an array of that string.
3. That string should be stored in cookie.
4. You should write functions, which creates an empty history array (yes, it's trivial), adds an item to the history (it's not, you have handle duplications), and the ones also mentioned: convert history array to string, forth and back.
5. So, if these routines are ready, you can add "add page to history" function on your each page.

Even such simple things should be *designed*, else you're lost.

Answer (score -1):

You need to work on the IP address which will be your unique entry in dbtable
store the search against this ipaddress in another dbtable.
show him the results on every visit 
first check whether user has an entry in your dbtable if no then first entry will go into that table and appropriate search will be entered to the second dbtable which has linked to this main table.
If your working on the cookie it may not be helpful if cookie gets deleted on any situation you may loose the user data and you have to setcookie everytime and have to maintain the db entry for that particular cookie.
rather store that fetched values into cookie. you no need to fetch the table on every page visit.

Comment: Working with IP-addresses would be a bad idea. Since a lot of users won't have static addresses they will visit with new addresses from time to time and wind up with no data. Even worse, other users might get to see your earlier visits. No a cookie solution would be much better, even if the data might be lost if the user clears his/her cookies.

Comment: but i wants to do it with cookies

Comment: Thanks Karl for correcting. I didn't think in that way..

You can set every user a unique cookie . with that cookie name create folder in that maintain xml formatted data for every visit.As your don't want to use a database and maintain cookie for this visits too this will increase every time user visits your site. May be this will be helpful